# d3d9 client area getting erased if window is moved out of viewable rect

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I am using DirectX 9 for making a UI (windowed). As I move the window out off the screen (i.e. drag it till some part of window is not visible and then drag it back) the part that was not visible gets erased. I tried making the same using DirectX 10 and it works fine. Why does DirectX 9 has this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: That's how Windows works. You should handle the `WM_PAINT` message. When you receive that message, redraw your program's window. Also, you should always use newer versions of DirectX, unless you want to target Windows XP.  PS: Also I don't know why only DX9 has this problem.

Comment: Well I Kinda Solved it...part of window was getting erased because of WM_ERASEBKGND Message being send to it.... so i specified WS_POPUP as window style and now it works flawlessly..

Comment: Did you try to redraw when you receive `WM_PAINT`? Y'know it's always better to do it the "official" way. If you prefer to handle the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message, just `return true;` and Windows will think that you erased the background (when you actually didn't).